# Latest updates to Lubuntu 18.04.4 LTS 32-bit create almost impossible graphics issues

Tags: updates

Since the last two updates, my laptop screen is filled with horizontal black bars that makes it impossible to work with. Also happens with an external monitor. I reinstalled Lubuntu and everything was fine, until I updated again, at which time the issue reappeared.

It looks like a dark 'virus' spreading across the computer screen.

The laptop is an IBM T41; 2 gb ram; I installed Lubuntu with the help of forcepae.

**I do not know if this is a bug or if the update simply goes beyond the capacities of my laptop.**

Solutions?

Comment: What is your video card and which drivers are you using?

Comment: Very hard to actually see but from copying and pasting into Firefox address bar I can see [AMD/ATI] RV200/M7 [Mobility Radeon 7500] ...It really is a mess. I am using whatever drivers Lubuntu installs by default.

Comment: Too messy to see much more. However, Lubuntu splash screen works fine on shutdown... which I guess is a clue as to what the problem is. (I am not a very technical person). Startup shows clearly in text that version is now 18.04.5

Comment: Did you need to use the `forcepae --forcepae` to install Lubuntu?  (I need to use it for a r50p I have as it's got a very old pentium M, so it's a clue as to you having a earlier pentium M). I use Lubuntu on a `ibm thinkpad t43 (pentium m, 1.5gb ram, radeon x300) (no `forcepae` was required), but to read your hardware I'd recommend the use of `sudo lshw -C video` (or *list hardware of class video*, `sudo` elevates privileges) which should be added to your question (please don't provide additional information via comment).

Comment: I did have to use forcepae with Lubuntu and this laptop. No problems until the most recent updates. For now, I have switched to bodhi linux which does not use PAE on 32-bit version. Bodhi linux is fully updated and working great. No problems. So I guess this is one 'solution.' I like Lubuntu but latest updates are a bad fit with this laptop and I cannot see enuf - bad graphics - to fix it. So I changed. Bodhi Linux is minimal and fast. I also tried Debian but could not get a GUI to work (probably my lack of expertise).

Comment: I suspect it's not bodhi, but the fact that Bodhi is using an older kernel (ie. if you type `uname -r` you'll see something older than 5.4 which was the kernel upgrade that your box had issues with.  If you'd switched to GA kernel (instead of HWE) on Lubuntu I believe your problem would have gone.. Yes Debian would have worked too (older kernel for Buster or any earlier release)

Comment: Do these older kernels pose any type of security risk or is it just about better performance with the newer kernels brought in by Lubuntu?

Comment: I won't speak to Bodhi, but Canonical/Ubuntu backports all security fixes back to the 4.15 kernel for Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (and flavors like Lubuntu). The benefit of HWE is later kernel modules (*drivers*) for users with newer equipment, but 4.15 is the more *stable*.

Comment: Newer features though (eg. WireGuard for VPN) is only back-ported to 5.4 by Canonical/Ubuntu, not earlier kernels so that *newer feature* won't be available (users may see that as security related, but it's new features and not security related to the kernel itself)

Comment: You are right about the older kernel - 4.9.0-6-686 - Bodhi seems to just use ubuntu servers when updating, so would that not automatically include kernel fixes with sudo apt update and upgrade? (which I did)

Comment: Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic, Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic on this site. The on-topic link provides alternate SE sites for non-Ubuntu OSes.  No kernel fixes won't work (would only hinder a debian kernel) on the wrong/older kernels.  (*If you're auditing the mixing of Ubuntu & Debian packages you'll be okay*)